# WP Rest endpoint with custom post type and ACF Fields

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, rest-api, endpoints

I am trying to create a REST api get to fetch projects and return them as JSON. I am trying to create a new endpoint, where I am trying to fetch the CPT and the other Advanced Custom Fields.

So far I can retrieve all posts from my custom post type but I would like to get the ACF (fields) as well.

```
function ldl_get_projects( $data ) {
  $posts = get_posts([
    'post_type'         => 'maps_projects',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
  ]);

  if (empty( $posts ) ) {
    return null;
  }

  $data = [];

  foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $api_content = [
        'name'  => $post->post_title,
        'description'  // ACF
        'cargo'  => // ACF 
        'services'  =>  // ACF
        'origin'  => // ACF
        'destination'  =>  // ACF
        'specifics'  =>  // ACF
        'long'  => // ACF
        'lat'  => // ACF
        'gallery'  => // ACF
    ];
    $data[] = $api_content;
  }

  return $data;
}
```

As you can see, the fields marked with  // ACF need to fetch the ACF field.
Can someone assist me a little further with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Advanced custom fields uses `get_field()` function to retrieve the fields. So, all you have to do is to retrieve them by using:

```
$field = get_field('field_name', $post->ID, 'format_value');
```

for each of your fields in the loop. You can read [this](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) page for more information.

Questions about plugins are off-topic here, That's why your question haven't receive much attention in 4 days. But since it was a simple problem i posted the answer.

Comment: How we could retrieve the post via WP REST in first place using ACF though? Cause if I understand correctly the ACF DOC the get_field( ) functon does not grab it from WP REST, right?